# Cannot POST an ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
 $.ajax({
        type        : 'POST', // define the type of HTTP verb we want to use (POST for our form)
        contentType : 'json',
        beforeSend  : function(request){
            request.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
        },
        url         : 'https://fedgis.com/NAGMapService/NAGMapService.aspx', // the url where we want to POST
        data        : school, // our data object
        dataType    : 'jsonp', // what type of data do we expect back from the server
                    encode          : true

    })
```

This is my code for posting some form data, but I have been getting the following error showing up in my console:

```
GET https://my_url.aspx?
callback=jQuery32103473…
age%20School&address=Ruby&website=www.hs.com&twitter=%23hs&_=1501421197069 
send @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
ajax @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
(anonymous) @ magic.js:20
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
q.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.min.js:3
```

I cannot figure out why.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you paste the content of `school`?

Comment: @Y2H `var school = {
            'action' : $('input[name=action]').val(),
            'type' : $('input[name=type]').val(),
            'school': $('input[name=school]').val(),
            'Name'              : $('input[name=Name]').val(),
            'address'             : $('input[name=address]').val(),
            'website'    : $('input[name=website]').val(),
            'twitter'    : $('input[name=twitter]').val()
        };`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your `school` variable. The jQuery selectors are missing innermost quotations. For instance:

```
$('input[name=type]').val()
```

Should actually be

```
$("input[name='type']").val()
```

and so on. The first syntax is not a proper syntax recognized by the jQuery library.